# live search filter submit button generated by c# code

Tags: javascript

I have a div which contains more than 50 input submit button. I want to implement a live filtering as done in [Data Tables](http://datatables.net/), the problem is i cannot keep my submit buttons inside tables, so can anyone suggest some approach, so that i can filter those input buttons as i enter something in the search text box.
Also these input submit buttons are generated by c# coding inside a panel.

i tried with [jquery.livesearch](https://github.com/nakajima/jquery-livesearch)

**Jquery**

```
   $('#searchbox').search('(".btn-pr").attr("value")', function (on) {
        on.reset(function () {
            $('.btn-pr').show();
        });
        on.empty(function () {
            $('#lblemp').show();
        });
        on.results(function (results) {
            $('.btn-pr').hide();

            results.show();
        });
    });
```

but as this one was used for number of li's inside ul, the selector passed in the `search` function was `#names li`, what selector and how (in place of **(".btn-pr").attr("value")**) should i pass so that it searches the values of those submit buttons, and hides which doesnt match.

**aspx**

```
<div id="div_items2" style="float:right; margin-top:10px; width:500px; height:400px; margin-right:5px; overflow:auto;">

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlCategories">

        <center><asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Estimate"></asp:Label></center><br />


    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlProducts" Visible="false" Width="100%">

        <center><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Estimate | Category: "></asp:Label><asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></center>

        <asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Back" onclick="btnBack_Click" CssClass="btn-nav" /><br /><br />

    </asp:Panel>


</div>
```

pnlProducts panel is generated with those input buttons during run.

Comment: You will need to provide the original HTML of your div.

Comment: It is just a asp:panel, and the c# coding is generating input submit buttons, the div i was talking about was at runtime which contains the input buttons, otherwise there is a div which contains a asp panel

Comment: Does this mean you aren't able to show us some HTML?

Comment: @MCL no its not like that, i have added the code.

Comment: @MCL do u want me to give how it is rendered in browser? `div_items2` div has another div inside dynamically generated, which contains different input submit buttons with same class.

Comment: I have never worked with ASP, but if I understand correctly, you have provided the server side code. In consequence, rendered HTML should be sent to the client browser, shouldn't it? If so, can you post the rendered HTML, too?

Comment: @MCL added the client code.

Comment: Your question is still pretty unclear to me. For starters, I don't see any "search text box". When do you want to "filter" your buttons and what is your expected outcome?